# tcpdump syntax for only capturing traffic coming to a specific virtual interface / local IP

Tags: linux, centos, centos5, tcpdump, packet-capture

CentOS 5.x

I need to collect a packet capture of https requests going to a specific IP address / virtual interface.  Is there a specific switch/parameter for tcpdump that will allow that? The other IPs receive a lot of traffic so I'd prefer to not capture data pertaining to them and have to filter them out later... .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
tcpdump -i any dst host your.ip.add.ress and port https
```

use http instead of https if you want to capture port 80 instead of 443 - or just use the numbers directly if you like. (The http/https names are mapped to the port numbers via lookup in `/etc/services`)

Comment: +1 for correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

```
tcpdump -n -i <INTERFACE> host <IP>
```

That should do it. -n will not resolve names.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
tcpdump -i any dst host your.ip.add.ress and port 80
```

Comment: wrong port for https